# Android voice input hangs my application on Meizu M5

Tags: android, voice-recognition, voice, google-voice, google-voice-search

I use dialogless voice input in my Android app:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MyRecognitionListener listener = new MyRecognitionListener();
    sr = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);       
    sr.setRecognitionListener(listener);

    findViewById(R.id.bt1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onButtonClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new 
            Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);    
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,"voice.recognition.query");           
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en_US");
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, "en_US");
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_ONLY_RETURN_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, "en_US");
            sr.startListening(intent);
        }
   });     
}
```

Some users reported that the app hangs after button click (in the onButtonClick listener) on Meizu M5. There are no any problems with other devices. One Meizu M5 user sent the following error report:

```
Stack:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4543)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5317)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21648)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5896)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:948)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:809)
at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:102)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4538)
... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to bind to service Intent { act=android.speech.RecognitionService cmp=com.mediatek.voicecommand/.service.VoiceWakeupRecognitionService }
at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1421)
at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1385)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:604)
at android.speech.SpeechRecognizer.startListening(SpeechRecognizer.java:287)
at com.TestAPP.MainActivity.onBtClick(Unknown Source)
... 12 more
```

Could you please help how to solve this problem with Meizu M5?

Comment: Can't help without log.

Comment: I've updated my post and added log.

Comment: SecurityException may suggest it's a permission problem. check this direction

Comment: Looks like you may need to define `com.mediatek.voicecommand.service.VoiceWakeupRecognitionService` in manifest

Comment: Added the following permission, but it didn't help: <uses-permission android:name="com.mediatek.voicecommand.service.VoiceWakeupRecognitionService" /> What do I do wrong?